# Is there a uncensored version of Tokyo Ghoul?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I couldn't find an uncensored version of Tokyo Ghoul.

Was it even released yet? If not, I would like to know when it estimated to be released.
(I'm sure it isn't going to stay like this forever.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DVDs will be uncensored.

They are not fully released yet (Volume 3 is coming out on the 28th of November, Volume 4 December 26th ), nor released in English speaking territories.

I expect it may take another few months before it is picked up by English licencors (streaming rights have been purchased, but DVD rights aren't up for grabs just yet).

[Ref](http://www.fandompost.com/2014/09/13/tokyo-ghoul-japanese-anime-dvdbd-releases-get-commercial-collection/)

Comment: "Uncensored". Even though aside for only a couple scenes most of the stuff that was censored was of a level most would consider ALREADY censored, and has gotten a lot of backlash over it.